# Performance issues with animations using StreamBuilder and flutter_animate

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-animation, flutter-futurebuilder, flutter-streambuilder

I'm encountering performance issues with animations in my Flutter app after transitioning from using **`FutureBuilder`** to **`StreamBuilder`** and integrating StreamProvider to fetch data dynamically from **`Firebase Firestore`**.

I've tried running in release mode. The animations still seem to be very junky and delayed. I'm using https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_animate for animations.

Interestingly, reverting to **`FutureBuilder`** restores normal animation behavior.

Any guidance or potential solutions to optimize animation performance while leveraging Firestore streams would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Here's a snippet of my database service fetching the data:

```
class DatabaseService {
  final FirebaseFirestore _db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  Stream<List<Person>> streamBirthdays() {
    return _db.collection('birthdays').snapshots().map((result) {
      return result.docs.map((doc) {
        final person = Person.fromJson(doc.data());
        person.id = doc.id;
        return person;
      }).toList();
    });
  }
}
```

In my app's setup, I'm using MultiProvider to manage different providers, including a StreamProvider:

```
runApp(
  MultiProvider(
    providers: [
      ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => settingsController),
      StreamProvider<List<Person>>(
        create: (context) => databaseService.streamBirthdays(),
        initialData: initialData,
      ),
    ],
    child: MyApp(
      settingsController: settingsController,
      savedThemeMode: savedTterhemeMode,
    ),
  ),
);
```

Within my UI, I consume the stream and play animations:

```
return Consumer<List<Person>>(
builder: (context, birthdayList, _) {

        if (birthdayList.isEmpty) {
          return Center(
            child: Text(
              message,
            ),
          ).animate().fadeIn();
        }
    
        return BirthdayListOld(birthdays: birthdayList);
      },
    );
```